# Best way to convert a List<Tuple<double, double>> to [,] array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am reading two columns of data from database, I want to create a `multidimensional array [,]` with pairs like,

```
double[,] arr = new double[,] { {val1,val2},{val1,val2}...{val1,val2} };
```

As I do not know the size of database data I am using a **list**.

So I have

```
List<Tuple<double, double>> Aux = new List<Tuple<double, double>>(); 

//THIS EMULATES READING DATABASE 
Aux.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(1.333,122.3));
Aux.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(2.343,142.3));
...
Aux.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(1.222,132.3));
if (Aux.Count > 0)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (Tuple<double, double> item in Aux)
    {
        res[index, 0] = item.Item1;
        res[index, 1] = item.Item2;
        index++;
    }
}
```

How would I get result like:

```
double[,] arr = new double[,] { 
{ 1.333,122.3 }, 
{ 2.343,142.3 }, 
...
{1.222,132.3}
};
```

Comment: `double[][] array = Aux.Select(x => new[] { x.Item1, x.Item2 }).ToArray();`

Comment: @L.B how to get [,] instead of [][] ?

Comment: @L.B There is a difference between multidimensional and jagged array.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks but that is why I didn't post it as an answer.....

Comment: Take a look at this post and make some changes then I think it should be what you want to achieve:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544513/converting-a-delimited-string-to-2-d-array

Comment: what you have is correct

Comment: What method would you recommend to be more effective ?

Comment: no, it's the same thing. Just using LINQ instead of the external accumulator for the index.

Comment: your original code is probably about as fast as it is going to get.  Even with the `for` example I have below I'm not out performing a simple `foreach` with the accumulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputData = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
                            .Select(i => Tuple.Create(10d * i, 1d * i))
                            .ToList();

{ // fastest
    var outputData = new double[inputData.Count, 2];
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in inputData)
    {
        outputData[index, 0] = item.Item1;
        outputData[index, 1] = item.Item2;
        index++;
    }
}

{ // slightly slower
    var outputData = new double[inputData.Count, 2];
    for (var index = inputData.Count - 1; index > -1; index--)
    {
        var tupple = inputData[index];
        outputData[index, 0] = tupple.Item1;
        outputData[index, 1] = tupple.Item2;
    }
}

{ // much slower
    var outputData = new double[inputData.Count, 2];
    foreach (var item in inputData.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i }))
    {
        outputData[item.Index, 0] = item.Value.Item1;
        outputData[item.Index, 1] = item.Value.Item2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# 7.0 or above:

```
var testTupleList = new List<(double, double)>() {
    (1.333,122.3),
    (2.343,142.3)
};

List<double[]> result =testTupleList.Select(data => data.ToTuple()
   .GetType()
   .GetProperties()
   .Select(property => property.GetValue(data.ToTuple()))
   .Cast<double>()
   .ToArray()).ToList();
```